# Github Build Getting Failed for AWS EC2 Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, amazon-ec2, github-actions

I am try to Auto deploy My SpringBoot Code to EC2 and Have added Docker and Github actions as below I am getting error Below. I am fairly new to AWS. I have added secret keys in secret. Rest Yaml is doing. Please help me regarding this.

Below is the yaml file I added

I have used Below link to follow as a tutorial

https://medium.com/geekculture/deploy-your-spring-boot-java-application-to-aws-ec2-using-github-actions-and-docker-e28c456a4b1a

```
name: Deploy AWS EC2
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
      - main
jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Get Github action IP
        id: ip
        uses: haythem/public-ip@v1.2

      - name: AWS configure
        uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
        with:
          aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID  }}
          aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
          aws-region: ${{ secrets.AWS_DEFAULT_REGION }}

      - name: Add github actions IP to security group
        env:
          AWS_SECURITY_GROUP: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECURITY_GROUP }}
        run: |
          aws ec2 authorize-security-group-ingress --group-id ${{ env.AWS_SECURITY_GROUP }} --protocol tcp --port 22 --cidr ${{ steps.ip.outputs.ipv4 }}/16
          sleep 10
      - name: Deploy on AWS EC2
        env:
          PRIVATE_KEY: ${{ secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY  }}
          HOSTNAME: ${{ secrets.HOSTNAME  }}
          USER_NAME: ${{ secrets.USERNAME  }}
          ECR_REGISTRY: ${{ steps.login-ecr.outputs.registry }}
        run: |
          echo "$PRIVATE_KEY" > private_key.pem && chmod 600 private_key.pem
          ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i private_key.pem ${USER_NAME}@${HOSTNAME} '
            rm -rf /home/ec2-user/https://github.com/cloudyape/metafy-back.git
            git clone https://github.com/cloudyape/metafy-back.git
            cd metafy_back
            git checkout main
            git pull origin main
            sudo chmod +x ./deploy.sh
            ./deploy.sh
          '
          rm -rf private_key.pem
      - name: Remove github actions IP from security group
        env:
          AWS_SECURITY_GROUP: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECURITY_GROUP }}
        run: |
          aws ec2 revoke-security-group-ingress --group-id ${{ env.AWS_SECURITY_GROUP }} --protocol tcp --port 22 --cidr ${{ steps.ip.outputs.ipv4 }}/16
        if: always()
```

Below is the error I am getting in the actions panel.

```
s
2s
Run echo "$PRIVATE_KEY" > private_key.pem && chmod 600 private_key.pem
  echo "$PRIVATE_KEY" > private_key.pem && chmod 600 private_key.pem
  ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i private_key.pem ${USER_NAME}@${HOSTNAME} '
    rm -rf /home/***/https://github.com/cloudyape/metafy-back.git
    git clone https://github.com/cloudyape/metafy-back.git
    cd metafy_back
    git checkout main
    git pull origin main
    sudo chmod +x ./deploy.sh
    ./deploy.sh
  '
  rm -rf private_key.pem
  shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
  env:
    AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: ***
    AWS_REGION: ***
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ***
    AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ***
    PRIVATE_KEY: ***
    HOSTNAME: ***
    USER_NAME: ***
    ECR_REGISTRY: 
  
Warning: Permanently added '***' (ED25519) to the list of known hosts.
Load key "private_key.pem": error in libcrypto
***@***: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
Error: Process completed with exit code 255.
```

Comment: That's a strange tutorial. Typically you build a docker image on your CI system like github actions and then upload it to a repo. Then on the server, you pull the docker image onto the host. This tutorial instead checks out and builds the docker image on the target server, which defeats the purpose of docker as a distribution tool. There is also at least one bug that was easy to spot in the tutorial's shell script. I would would be weary about following that guide.

Answer (score -1):

im facing this kind of error and i put `sudo` on every command

e.g `sudo git pull`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).